# Regex: ONly Allow Upper case AND specific numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create regex and test in javascript.

RULE:
The text should only be 8 characters.
Only contain Upper case *and* numbers 1-5
No lower case or special characters or 6-7 numbers.

example:

```
12345678 -- false
a2345678 -- false
aabbccdd -- false
AABB33DD -- true // contains BOTH uppercase and 
                    numbers between 1-5 and nothing else
AABB88DD -- false 
AABBCCDD -- false
AABB3.DD -- false
```

CODE:

```
 var pattern = new RegExp("^(?=.*[1-5])(?=.*[A-Z]).+$");
 pattern.test(code)
```

I'm not able to crate the right regex. Can anyone please help?

Comment: `/^[A-Z1-5]{8}$/`

Comment: @ASDFGerte This isn't working. it accepts all Uppercase text like `AAAAAAAA`

Comment: Yes, i interpreted it that way - from your comment, i assume you want at least one letter and at least one number, but don't really see that reflected in your question. If you want at least one, just add a lookahead checking for one somewhere.

Comment: So it must contain at least one char and at least 1 digit?

Comment: @SalmanA Should only accept the combination of uppercase and numbers between 1-5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```js
^(?=.*[1-5])(?=.*[A-Z])[A-Z1-5]{8}$
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/tkKV5E/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [1-5]                    any character of: '1' to '5'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [A-Z]                    any character of: 'A' to 'Z'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [A-Z1-5]{8}              any character of: 'A' to 'Z', '1' to '5'
                           (8 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```